# Use alias "case when" in where clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an error:

> Invalid column name Temp

I want use column `Temp` in `where` clause. How do I do it?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[R_rpt1]
        @ltt int
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YeuCauId) STT, a.name,
                CASE WHEN a.tt = 0 THEN 0
                    WHEN (a.tt = 1 AND a.code IN (Select code from SCHEMAB.dbo.databaseB)) THEN 3
                    WHEN  (a.tt = 1 ) THEN 1
                    WHEN a.tt=2 THEN 2
                    END as Temp
        FROM ViewPhieuYeuCau a
        WHERE Temp = @ltt
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subquery:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[R_rpt1]
    @ltt int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YeuCauId) STT, a.name,
                CASE
                    WHEN a.tt = 0 THEN 0
                    WHEN a.tt = 1 AND a.code IN (Select code from SCHEMAB.dbo.databaseB) THEN 3
                    WHEN a.tt = 1 THEN 1
                    WHEN a.tt=2 THEN 2
                END as Temp
        FROM ViewPhieuYeuCau a
    ) t
    WHERE Temp = @ltt
END
```

Since `WHERE` clause is executed first before the `SELECT`, `Temp` is not yet recognized by the `WHERE` clause. To fix this, you have to use a subquery.

[Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)